# Try to look for all space missions in the solar system which have become a satellite of their target

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

The DBPedia SPARQL endpoint doesn't give any results.

What is wrong?

```
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbc: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
SELECT distinct ?s ?o
FROM <http://dbpedia.org/>
WHERE{
?s dcterms:subject/skos:broader*
dbc:Discovery_and_exploration_of_the_Solar_System ;
dbp:satelliteOf ?o .
}
```

Comment: what means "have become a satellite"?

Comment: also, the property `dbp:satelliteOf` is simply just used for asteroids,  moons, etc. see `select * where {?s dbp:satelliteOf ?o} LIMIT 1000` - which bindings to `?s` do you expect to get? I mean, the `?s` are basically space missions or not? why should those be satellite of something?

Comment: A query can only deliver results that exist in the data being queried. The data you want does not seem to be part of the data in DBpedia, nor Wikipedia. (You might check this by looking at the full description of one mission which you would expect to satisfy your query.) This seems to present an opportunity for you to enhance both by adding such data to Wikipedia, which will soon thereafter become part of DBpedia.